# How to install Web Deploy for Hosting Servers on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, iis, webdeploy

The Web Platform Installer fails to install Web Deploy for Hosting Servers on Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To fix this, first install the missing components using Server Manager, Manage, Add Role and Features. I think these are the ones required: Logging Tools, Request Monitor, .Net Extensibility, ASP.Net, ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters, Management Service. I ended up with the following for my needs.

[image: IIS roles and features]

Next install *Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers* using the Web Platform Installer. (If it fails, note which components it depended on, install as above and try again.)

At this stage if you look for Deploy again in the Platform Installer it won't be installed, even though it says it was successful.

Go to Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs, find Web Deploy and choose Modify, Next, then Change.

Set *IIS Deployment Handler* to *Entire feature will be installed*, Next etc.

[image: Web Deploy 3.6 Setup]

The Deploy menu will now appear in IIS Manager (restart it first if you already had it open) and Web Platform Installer will see that it's installed.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO !
Thanks !

Comment: Bravo! You are and my hero too!

Comment: **Fiiinaaaalyy!!!! A solution**. I was having an issue with missing `BackupScripts.ps1` (local on my machine and on the server) - Uninstall web deploy from control panel, enabling `IIS Managerment service` from features, then install web deploy 3.6 for hosting from Web Platform Installer. BOOM -> backup scripts appeared.

Comment: The above steps for re-install/modify installation worked for me on a win 11 IIS 10. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow franzos answer and even though it worked in the end and resolved my issue, there was one detail missing:

> At this stage if you look for Deploy again in the Platform Installer
>   it won't be installed, even though it says it was successful.
>
> Go to Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs, find Web Deploy and
>   choose Modify, Next, then Change.
>
> Set IIS Deployment Handler to Entire feature will be installed, Next
>   etc.

On my windows server core there is no "Control Panel" or other access to "Add or Remove Programs"

What resolved it for me was downloading the .msi package for WebDeploy to the server and running it from cmd.

```
msiexec /L msdeployinstall.log /I <path_to_msi>
```

This runs the installation wizard and you can change the installation with:
Set *IIS Deployment Handler* to *Entire feature will be installed*, Next etc.
as described by franzo.

Best regards and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this on a fresh azure server 2022 node and after doing all of Franzo's stuff it still didn't work.

I decided to connect the IIS on the new node to the IIS on the old node just to see what it did... I hit "Connect to a Server...", put in the IP of the old node, and when it connected it told me the new node was missing some extensions.  The web deploy was one of them and it installed it for me.